# Loops, Scoring, and File Management for "Snakes & Ladders" in Python

Tags: python

## Thanks for checking!

I'm just seeing what this site is all about and need help with an assignment. So far, I actually have a functioning game of "Snakes & Ladders" in Python. What I need it to do is make it so that ***when the game is over, the list of 5 best scores is displayed, then the user is asked if he wants to play again.*** I am having issues with the loop of the overall game, and saving scores. If there is anyone out there that wants to give this a try, your assistance would be greatly appreciated. I'm a noob.

## So, here's what I have so far:

```
from random import *

# Basic Game Setup

def setup_game():

    players=6 
    while True:
        try:
            print("How many players are in the game?")
            players = int(input())
            if players > 4 or players < 2:
                print("Must be less than 5 and greater than 1")
            else:
                break
        except ValueError:
                print("Must be a number")

    names = {}
    for i in range(1,players+1):
        while True:
            name = input("What is the name of Player {}? ".format(i))
            if not name in names:
                names[name] = 0
                break
            else:
                print('Cannot have duplicate names')
        
    return names

    
# Dice Roll 

def roll_dice():
    return randint(2,12)


# Short Game

def move_player(player, current_pos):

    snake_squares = {20:15, 21:2, 50:40,52:18}
    ladder_squares = {4:15,7:90,35:45,60:80,77:98}

    total_moves = 0  #total_moves is where I'm trying to keep score
    
    throw = roll_dice()
    next_pos = current_pos + throw
    total_moves += throw
        
    print("{0} rolled a {1} and is now on square {2}".format(player, throw, next_pos))

    if next_pos in snake_squares:
        print("Player got bitten by a snake and is now on square {}".format(snake_squares[next_pos]))
        next_pos = snake_squares[next_pos]
    elif next_pos in ladder_squares:
        print("Player climbed a ladder and is now on square {}".format(ladder_squares[next_pos]))
        next_pos = ladder_squares[next_pos]
    return next_pos


# Long Game

def move_player2(player, current_pos):

    snake_squares2 = {20:15, 21:2, 50:40,52:18,99:6,170:100,190:171,199:111}
    ladder_squares2 = {4:15,7:90,35:45,60:80,77:98,2:155,55:166,66:177,77:188,100:150,171:180}

    total_moves = 0
    
    throw = roll_dice()
    next_pos = current_pos + throw
    total_moves += throw
        
    print("{0} rolled a {1} and is now on square {2}".format(player, throw, next_pos))

    if next_pos in snake_squares2:
        print("Player got bitten by a snake and is now on square {}".format(snake_squares2[next_pos]))
        next_pos = snake_squares2[next_pos]
    elif next_pos in ladder_squares2:
        print("Player climbed a ladder and is now on square {}".format(ladder_squares2[next_pos]))
        next_pos = ladder_squares2[next_pos]
    return next_pos


# Game Definition

def game(players):
    winner = {}
    length = "s"
    print("{}, Welcome To Snakes And Ladders - Select s for short game or l for Long game".format(" ".join(players)))
    length = str(input())
   
    #Short
    while length == "s":

        # For each player
        for player, current_pos in players.items():

            # Move player
            players[player] = move_player(player, current_pos)

            # Check win
            if players[player] >= 100:
                return player

            # Next player
            input("Press Enter")


    # Long    
    while length == "l":
            
        # For each player
        for player, current_pos in players.items():

            # Move player
            players[player] = move_player2(player, current_pos)

            # Check win
            if players[player] >= 200:
                return player

            # Next player
            input("Press Enter")


    else:
        print("Error")

# Game Loop
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    players = setup_game()
    winner = game(players)
    total_moves = move_player
    print("{} won the game!!!!!".format(winner))

    input("Play Again? Press Enter".format(setup_game))     # game loop that doesn't work..
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a really good program, the loop issue can be fixed by using a while loop in the 'game loop':

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        players = setup_game()
        winner = game(players)
        total_moves = move_player
        print("{} won the game!!!!!".format(winner))
        input("Play Again? Press Enter".format(setup_game))
```

I would also recommend using '\n' in your code to neaten the output between turns.